# Output result in sequence of colors. Input from user one by one

Tags: ruby, arrays

The goal is for the computer to guess correctly 4 sequences of colors from the player. The player guesses one color through each instance of the loop. If computer guess correct, then the final output should output 4 sequences of the colors correct from the player. Duplicates are allowed. I was thinking of setting up an array and storing it with the first element. Then doing a push to add the next correct colors. Or another way is to do an each.index with |item, index| ?

```
colors = %w(red green orange yellow blue purple)

guess_counter = 0

while guess_counter < 4 do
  comp_guess = colors.sample 
  puts "Enter your guess: "
  guess = gets.chomp
  puts "Computer guessed: " + comp_guess
  if(guess == comp_guess)
    puts "You got it right."
    puts
  else
    puts "You got it wrong. Guess again."
    puts
  end
end
```

Running the program below is a sample.

```
Enter your guess:
red
Computer guessed: red
You got it right.

Enter your guess:
blue
Computer guessed: blue
You got it right.

Enter your guess:
yellow
Computer guessed: orange
You got it wrong. Guess again.

Enter your guess:
green
Computer guessed: green
You got it right.

Enter your guess:
orange
Computer guessed: yellow
You got it wrong. Guess again.

Enter your guess:
red
Computer guessed: red
You got it right.
```

So the output should be "The correct sequence is red, blue, green, red"

Comment: How can I store each correct guess, then output it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are also forgetting to increment `guess_counter` (which seems like it should only be incremented if the guess is correct) which is actually not needed if we are storing correct guesses.  Otherwise, just append to an array of guesses every time you guess correctly then print it using the `join` method:

```
colors = %w(red green orange yellow blue purple)

correct_guesses = []

while correct_guesses.size < 4 do
  comp_guess = colors.sample 
  puts "Enter your guess: "
  guess = gets.chomp
  puts "Computer guessed: " + comp_guess
  if(guess == comp_guess)
    puts "You got it right."
    puts
    correct_guesses << guess
  else
    puts "You got it wrong. Guess again."
    puts
  end
end

puts "The correct sequence is #{correct_guesses.join(', ')}"
```

Comment: How would I add a 2nd loop to count the correct guess up to 4. Then the overall loop as the total number of guess stop at 10?